# Print the line after a specific line

Tags: python, function, line

I have a function that checks a .txt file and gets some data from it after analyzing it.
I have a file with the name (Data.txt) which contains the below:

```
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/5.33

 description 4543

 trust upstream default

 trust 8021p outbound

 qos phb dscp disable

interface GigabitEthernet3/0/5.34

 description 4046

 trust upstream default

 trust 8021p outbound

interface GigabitEthernet3/0/5.35

 description 4584

 trust upstream default

 trust 8021p outbound

 qos phb dscp disable
```

The below function is to extract the interfaces which don't have  "qos phb dscp disable" under it.
So, the final result should be saved in a file (Data with no qos.txt)
with "interface GigabitEthernet3/0/5.34" in it.

**What I'm asking for**: I have tried to print the interface with its description, so the result will be:

```
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/5.34

 description 4046
```

Can anyone help me?

```
def noqos(Devicess):
        data = open('D:\Scripting Test/' + Devicess + '.txt').read()
        def no_qos(lines):
            # keep track of interfaces seen and which has qos
            interfaces = []
            has_qos = set()
            print (Devicess + '( No qos under interfaces )')
            print ("-----------------------------------------------------------")
            # scan the file and gather interfaces and which have qos
            for line in lines:
                if line.startswith('interface'):
                    interface = line.strip()
                    interfaces.append(interface)
                elif line.startswith(" qos"):
                    has_qos.add(interface)
    
            # report which interfaces do not have qos
            return [i for i in interfaces if i not in has_qos]
    
    
        lastnoqos = open(('D:\Scripting Test/Noqos/' + Devicess + ' no qos.txt'), "w")
        for interface in no_qos(data.split('\n')):
            # print(interface)
            # print ("\n")
            lastnoqos.write(interface + '\n')
noqos('Data')
```

Comment: So what doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the data to a list of dictionaries and then loop through them to find the interfaces you are looking for (and perhaps do some other processing as well):

```
data = """interface GigabitEthernet3/0/5.33
  description 4543
  trust upstream default
  trust 8021p outbound
  qos phb dscp disable
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/5.34
  description 4046
  trust upstream default
  trust 8021p outbound
interface GigabitEthernet3/0/5.35
  description 4584
  trust upstream default
  trust 8021p outbound
  qos phb dscp disable"""

with open('D:\Scripting Test/' + Devicess + '.txt') as textfile:
    data = textfile.read()
    interfaces = []
    for line in data.split("\n"):          # go through lines
        k,_ = line.strip().split(" ",1)    # get the first keyword
        if k=="interface":                 # add a dict() for new interfaces
            current = dict()               # which becomes the current one
            interfaces.append(current)
        current[k]=line                    # accumulate keywords in current 

for i in interfaces:              # find interfaces
    if "qos" not in i:            # without a "qos" keyword
        print(i["interface"])     # print name and description
        print(i["description"])

interface GigabitEthernet3/0/5.34
  description 4046
```

Comment: but data is a  txt file with variable content , how to convert txt file to a list of dictionaries  as you said

Comment: You already have the text file reading code in your example,I didn't repeat that part so that my example could be copied/pasted/tested independently.  I will add the two lines needed to get the data from the text file now.